# replaceWith without remove elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is html: (Sample)

```
<div class="lblTest well" data-src="001">Label 1</div>

to 

<a class="lblTest well" data-src="001" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom 1" >Label 1</a>
```

This is js:

```
$('.lblTest').each(function (i, n) {
    var $element = $(this);        
    $element.replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<a/>', {
            html: this.innerHTML,
            class: this.className,
            href: '#',
            'data-src':this.('dataSrc'), /// < ???
            'data-toggle':'tooltip',
            'data-placement':'bottom',
            'title':'Tooltip on bottom ' + (i + 1)
        });
    });
});
```

This code is incorrect:

```
'data-src':this.('dataSrc'), /// < ???
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/behrouzbash/v0L52yzw/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `dataSrc` attribute in the element. That should be

```
$(this).data("src"),
```